# accelerate_decelerate_interpolator no pause when animation ends and the next start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I try to achieve an animation like this one :

[image]

The code of my animation look like this :

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    >
</rotate>
```

and the result :

[image]

it's not that bad, but as you can see, every time the animation ends there is a small pause before the next start so I can't reach the same result as seen in the first gif. And I don't really know what I can modify to achieve that. With a `linear_interpolator` it's working but there is no accelerate/decelerate anymore.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would say try to change the interpolator. What you have used is AccelerateDecelerate Interpolator. Try changing it to only accelerate interpolator. more info here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html

Comment: I already tried everything and it always the same.